# How to determine if one graph lies within another (vertices on a Cartesian grid)

Tags: python, graph, networkx, image-segmentation, shapely

In my algorithm, I am finding graphs at different thresholds. Each graph G = (V,E). These are undirected graphs found using breadth first search. I would like to determine if the vertices of another graph G' = (V',E') lie within graph G. I am unfamiliar with graph algorithms so please let me know if you would like to see code or a more thorough explanation.

For example, If I have a graph G which is a square with 'corner' vertices (among others, but reduced for simplicity) of (0,0), (0,8), (8,8), and (8,0), then the smaller square defined by corner vertices (2,2), (2,4), (4,4), and (4,2) would lie within G. I am sorry if this is an obvious question, I am just unfamiliar with working with graphs and could use a pointer or two (keywords welcome).

Edit:
My algorithm works on the following matrix:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.zeros((9,9))
    for i in np.arange(1,8):
        for j in np.arange(1,8):
            A[i,j] = 1
    for i in np.arange(2,4):
        for j in np.arange(2,4):
            A[i,j] = 2
    print(A)
```

yields the matrix:

```
[[-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  2.  2.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1. -1.]
 [-1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1. -1.]]
```

To create two graphs:

[image: ] [[Imgur]]

With vertices:

```
V1 = [[(2.0, 1.333333), (1.333333, 3.0), (1.333333, 2.0), (2.0, 3.666667), (3.0, 3.666667), (3.666667, 3.0), (3.666667, 2.0), (3.0, 1.333333)]]
V2 = [[(1.0, 0.5), (0.5, 2.0), (0.5, 1.0), (0.5, 3.0), (0.5, 4.0), (0.5, 5.0), (0.5, 6.0), (0.5, 7.0), (1.0, 7.5), (2.0, 7.5), (3.0, 7.5), (4.0, 7.5), (5.0, 7.5), (6.0, 7.5), (7.0, 7.5), (7.5, 7.0), (7.5, 6.0), (7.5, 5.0), (7.5, 4.0), (7.5, 3.0), (7.5, 2.0), (7.5, 1.0), (7.0, 0.5), (6.0, 0.5), (5.0, 0.5), (4.0, 0.5), (3.0, 0.5), (2.0, 0.5)]]
```

And edge lists:

```
e1 = [[[1.333333, 2.0], [2.0, 1.333333]], [[1.333333, 3.0], [1.333333, 2.0]], [[2.0, 3.666667], [1.333333, 3.0]], [[2.0, 1.333333], [3.0, 1.333333]], [[2.0, 3.666667], [3.0, 3.666667]], [[3.0, 1.333333], [3.666667, 2.0]], [[3.666667, 3.0], [3.666667, 2.0]], [[3.0, 3.666667], [3.666667, 3.0]]]
e2 = [[[0.5, 1.0], [1.0, 0.5]], [[0.5, 2.0], [0.5, 1.0]], [[0.5, 3.0], [0.5, 2.0]], [[0.5, 4.0], [0.5, 3.0]], [[0.5, 5.0], [0.5, 4.0]], [[0.5, 6.0], [0.5, 5.0]], [[0.5, 7.0], [0.5, 6.0]], [[1.0, 7.5], [0.5, 7.0]], [[1.0, 0.5], [2.0, 0.5]], [[1.0, 7.5], [2.0, 7.5]], [[2.0, 0.5], [3.0, 0.5]], [[2.0, 7.5], [3.0, 7.5]], [[3.0, 0.5], [4.0, 0.5]], [[3.0, 7.5], [4.0, 7.5]], [[4.0, 0.5], [5.0, 0.5]], [[4.0, 7.5], [5.0, 7.5]], [[5.0, 0.5], [6.0, 0.5]], [[5.0, 7.5], [6.0, 7.5]], [[6.0, 0.5], [7.0, 0.5]], [[6.0, 7.5], [7.0, 7.5]], [[7.0, 0.5], [7.5, 1.0]], [[7.5, 2.0], [7.5, 1.0]], [[7.5, 3.0], [7.5, 2.0]], [[7.5, 4.0], [7.5, 3.0]], [[7.5, 5.0], [7.5, 4.0]], [[7.5, 6.0], [7.5, 5.0]], [[7.5, 7.0], [7.5, 
6.0]], [[7.0, 7.5], [7.5, 7.0]]]
```

I hope to use it on finding more complicated shapes like the following:

[image: ][[Imgur]]

In the second picture, I have a red shape inside of a green shape. Ideally, red shapes would lie within red shapes.

I can attach a full workable example, but it would include my whole algorithm and be pages long, with many functions! I basically want to use either input (V1, E1) and (V2, E2) into a function, which would tell me whether one lies within the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ray-casting to figure this out. It's a common method for dealing with this problem, so you can find additional information on it elsewhere too. The general description of the algorithm is this:

- G1 and G2 are graphs whose edges form a simple polygon/convex hull, where we are attempting to determine if G2 is inside G1.
- Choose some arbitrary direction in your space.
- For each vertex in G2, cast a ray (a line that starts from one point and extends infinitely in a single direction) in the direction you chose.
- If the vertex (a) intersects an edge of G1 an odd number of times OR (b) lies on one of those edges--> the vertex is inside of G1. For all other cases, the vertex is not inside of G1.
- G2 is inside of G1 if an only if each vertex of G2 is inside of G1.

This will involve the following subtasks
-Get a list of vertices for G2

-Casting the rays

-Detecting and counting intersection

If you loop through each vertex and draw a line by adding the value you are using to represent G2 on your matrix to all cells in the direction you choose, the intersection value would then just be the sum of the values you are using to represent G1 and G2. In your current case, because you're making squares, this is a little problematic. There may be a better algorithm for drawing the objects or a better way to detect intersections.

Lastly, for detecting if en edge lies on the graph, you should run the check for intersections BEFORE you loop through the vertices. If any of your vertices produce the intersection value before the ray casting, it will tell you that it is on the edge of G1. Mark that this vertex is inside G1, remove it from the list of vertices that need to be checked, and make note of this value so it doesn't count as an extra intersection for all

You may have to tweak this algorithm depending on things like whether you want to count nodes on the edge as inside or outside, or whether you need all vertices inside the figure, but I hope this is a helpful start.

Comment: I decided to go with matplotlib.pyplot's 'contains_points()' method. It works on 2D graphs. I wonder if the ray-casting approach would be more adaptable if (when) I go into 3D.

Comment: It looks like the same approach works and it might be the optimal approach, unless of course you come across a library that can take care of it without you having to implement your own algorithm. In fact, it looks like ray-casting might be the most efficient approach in certain circumstances because it looks like the other options use linear algebra that might be a little more complex to implement.

Comment: I was actually going to look into the time complexities of each. I'm a bit.. weary of implementing this myself. I'm not a pro at python. Though, how does one learn? By trying of course. Thank you. I may give this a whirl.

Comment: One thing I ran into: When I determine that, yes, g3 lies within g1, I want to then group g1 together with g3 and any other subgraphs g_i that lie within g1. What data structure might I use? I'm trying sets now, but I don't think this is going to work.